# jquery function not working after switching from grid to list

Tags: jquery, fadeto

I've a website which contains a switching jQuery function from grid to list.
In another external .js file there is the following function

```
$(function (){
$('.image a img').hover(
function () {
     $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.7);
     },
function(){
    $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
}
);
});
```

which is working only the first time.
If i'm switching from "grid" to "list" or viceversa, it doesn't work anymore.

In the google developer tool the inline style disappear after switching.
Is there any easy solution to "reload" the function above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you don't reset the queue. So if you mouse over/ mouse out fast. It will show nothing. Try this:

```
$('body').on("mouseenter", ".image a img", function () {
     $(this).stop(true, false).fadeTo('slow', 0.7);
   })
.on("mouseleave", ".image a img", function(){
    $(this).stop(true, false).fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```

Which will reset the queue, but not jump to the end. Also, you can use the LIVE element to keep the event alive on all items which change. Which is on in the new jQuery since 1.8

Comment: The problem is that the code is working until i use the "switch-grid" function. For the rest it's fine. Sorry if i wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Niels! It's working now, but the inline style in google developer tool still disappears. Any idea why?

Comment: jQuery places inline styles. But when its 100% or 0, it will get display none or block.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this"

```
$( '.image a img' ).on({
     mouseenter: function() {

        $( this ).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.7);

      },
      mouseleave: function() {

        $( this ).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);

     }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

To be sure i'd have to see more code, but perhaps the reason is that the quoted function binds `.hover` event to all elements matching the query `$('.image a img')` in the binding moment (which is on document ready event), so if you add new elements later (edit: which, I'm guessing, your switching function does?), even matching the query `$('.image a img')` `.hover` will not be defined for them. Switch to `$(.image container').on("mouseenter mouseleave",'.image a img', handlerInOut)`, where `.image container` is an element in which `.image a img` are, and see if it helps.